# Having problems with storing variable in classes

Tags: java

Please see ifmy logic is correct i do not know how to implement what i am trying to do. I am a beginner in java.

Game is a class which stores the Name and the Steps of that user after the game is complete.

[ First Method ]

```
private game[] gameArray = new game[10];

for(int i = 0; i <gameArray.length;i++){
         gameArray[i].setName(nameTxt.getText());
         gameArray[i].setpSteps(stepsCount);
    }
```

By Clicking History Button they will get the previous 10 people's name and steps.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
       "Player's Name No. of Steps"+
       "\n"+gameArray[i].toString());
```

-The Problem:

1) This code limits to only previous 10 results is there anyway i can get all the previous results

2) This code is not working!

[ Second Method - This is also not working! ]

```
private game[] gameArray = new game[10];

// Storing the name of player[i]

gameArray[i].setName(nameTxt.getName());

// Storing the number of steps player[i] took.

gameArray[i].setpSteps(stepsCount);

//Displaying previous 10 players name and steps

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
       "Player's Name No. of Steps"+
       "\n"+gameArray[i].toString());
```

Comment: When you say it's "not working", what do you mean? What do you expect and what is happening? An error? Nothing? Wrong data is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points:

- you can't directly convert an array to a `String` through `toString()` because it isn't supported in Java, you should use `Arrays.toString(..)`
- Java arrays have static size, if you want to store the whole history you will need a dynamic data structure as an `ArrayList<Game>` or a `LinkedList<Game>`
- name of classes should be capitalized (`Game`, not `game`)
- without knowing the internals of your `Game` class it's impossible to tell what is not working and why it is not working, we don't even know what it is supposed to do exactly

Comment: where should i put the Arrays.toString(..)? Thank you i wasnt aware of the dynamic data structure.